# Can't access a method from another class

Tags: c#, oop, methods

There are many similar questions already answered but their solution didn't help me understand how to solve mine. That's why I decided to ask.
I have a class *GSMCallHistoryTest* with a method:

```
public void DisplayCallHistory()
{
    Console.WriteLine(theGSM.PrintCallHistory()); 
}
```

I also have a class *GSM* with constructors, properties, and the PrintCallHistory() method:

```
public string PrintCallHistory()
{
    StringBuilder printCallhistory = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (Call call in this.callHistory)
    {
        printCallhistory.Append(call.ToString());
    }
    return printCallhistory.ToString();
}
```

What I'm trying to do in *MAIN* is call the DisplayCallHistory() method:

```
DateTime testCallDate1 = new DateTime(2015, 03, 15, 17, 50, 23);
DateTime testCallDate2 = new DateTime(2015, 03, 15, 20, 20, 05);
DateTime testCallDate3 = new DateTime(2015, 03, 17, 11, 45, 00);

var callHistory = new List<Call>
{
    new Call(testCallDate1, 0889111111, 5),
    new Call(testCallDate2, 0889222222, 10),
    new Call(testCallDate3, 0889333333, 3)
};
GSM theGSM = new GSM("MODEL", "MANUFACTURER", callHistory);
theGSM.DisplayCallHistory(); // <<<< Problem
```

The problem is:

```
Task_1___GSM.GSM' does not contain a definition for 'DisplayCallHistory' 
and no extension method 'DisplayCallHistory' accepting a first argument of type
'Task_1___GSM.GSM' could be found (are you missing a using directive 
or an assembly reference?)
```

Seems like a pretty common and obvious error but I don't know how to fix it. I can think of 2 things:

1. Make the method I want to call static(and then fix a ton of problems which this may lead to).
2. Create an object from GSMCallHistoryTest. But this doesn't seem right to me. Use an object from another class with another object to use the method from the first one!? This can't possibly work.

Comment: .... `DisplayCallHistory()` belongs to `GMSCallHistoryTest` Not `GSM`

Comment: Shouldn't you be calling `theGSM.PrintCallHistory()` instead?

Comment: Yes, and I want to use it for a GSM object in main.
 Making GSM inherit GSMCallHistoryTest leads to StackOverflow.
@Rufus L, you actually do have a point. But I'm following this task:

Write a class GSMCallHistoryTest to test the call history functionality of the GSM class.
Create an instance of the GSM class.
Add few calls.
Display the information about the calls.

Comment: Why don't you just change your code to call the existing class method then? Not sure what GSMCallHistoryTest has to do with this, except that your existing code is trying to call a method from that class instead of the GSM class.

Comment: Maybe I should stop following the task conditions to the letter...
Guess I'll just put the methods in GSM class and use them from there. That would be a piece of cake. Then I'll ask one of the teachers why did they include that GSMCallHistoryTest in the first place.
P.S. Thanks for the edit, MAV!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading through the list of tasks you mentioned in your comment-reply to Rufus L, perhaps this is what you're supposed to be going for:

```
//Task 1 - Create GSMCallHistoryTest class
public class GSMCallHistoryTest
{
  private GSM theGSM;

  public void DisplayCallHistory()
  {
    //Create the calls
    DateTime testCallDate1 = new DateTime(2015, 03, 15, 17, 50, 23);
    DateTime testCallDate2 = new DateTime(2015, 03, 15, 20, 20, 05);
    DateTime testCallDate3 = new DateTime(2015, 03, 17, 11, 45, 00);
    var callHistory = new List<Call>
    {
      new Call(testCallDate1, 0889111111, 5),
      new Call(testCallDate2, 0889222222, 10),
      new Call(testCallDate3, 0889333333, 3)
    };

    //Tasks 2 and 3 - Create instance of theGSM and add the calls
    theGSM = new GSM("MODEL", "MANUFACTURER", callHistory);

    //Task 4 - Display information about the calls
    Console.WriteLine(theGSM.PrintCallHistory());
  }
}
```

Then you could call this from the main method of your application as

```
var callHistoryTest = new GsMCallHistoryTest();
callHistoryTest.DisplayCallHistory();
```

Comment: Hmm... not sure but seeing your code gives me an idea.
 I didn't consider the option of putting many tasks in one method. But I still can't see how this could work in main. It's not a static method and needs some sort of instance.
 And I don't understand the following:
  private GSM theGSM; >> you create an empty object withouth a constructor and it works.
Then you call a constructor and form the object with the specified parameters. Wow!
Needless to say, I'm new to OOP.

Comment: Right! A couple of minutes ago I wrote in haste: GSMCallHistoryTest.DisplayCallHistory() and wondered why it didn't work. And it was because I tried to access the method from the non-static class and not the object I had created. 
Anyway, your solution works and it makes sense! Thank you! :)

Comment: I'm happy to have helped!  Please remember to mark my answer as the one the that solved your question.  Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You say `GSMCallHistoryTest` has a function `DisplayCallHistory`()

But you call the function `DisplayCallHistory`() on `GSM`, which doesn't have that function, it has `PrintCallHistory()`

Comment: DisplayCallHistory() from 'GSMCallHistoryTest' is calling the PrintCallHistory() from 'GSM'. And in 'main' an object from class GSM is trying to call DisplayCallHistory(), the first one, that is.... this seems ridiculous. But the task says I have to write a GSMCallHistoryTest to test the call history. Boy... what a mess!